# How to create a dictionary using the the list of letters as keys with values being the uppercase version of the letters

Tags: python-3.x

How to create a dictionary using the list of letters as keys with values being the uppercase version of the letters.

Comment: Just looking for the following output:

Comment: The dictionary:
{'g': 'G', 'o': 'O', 't': 'T', 'v': 'V', 'i': 'I', 'f': 'F', 'z': 'Z', 'w': 'W', 'h': 'H', 'n': 'N', 'm': 'M', 'q': 'Q', 'k': 'K', 'j': 'J', 'u': 'U', 'r': 'R', 'y': 'Y', 'a': 'A', 'd': 'D', 'c': 'C', 'x': 'X', 's': 'S', 'b': 'B', 'e': 'E', 'p': 'P', 'l': 'L'}

Comment: You just answered it..

Answer (score 2):

Using a dict comprehension with all of your chosen letters will give you key:value pairs with 'lower':'UPPER'.

```py
lower_to_upper = {
    letter: letter.upper()
    for letter in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
}
```

Comment: First time I've seen one of those. There's always something new to learn with Python!

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension to build tuples that are input to create the dictionary.

```
mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c']
dict((i, i.upper()) for i in mylist)
```

output

```
{'a': 'A', 'b': 'B', 'c': 'C'}
```

Comment: could just do `{i: i.upper() for i in mylist}`, saves having to call `dict` and is a lot faster

Comment: Yes, I agree. I hadn't seen dict comprehensions before @GeeTransit's answer. Now I know.

Comment: tbf I only learnt about them relatively recently aswell, turns out using the syntax with `{` and `}` generates faster bytecode which is useful to know :)